# EFCore canConnect returning true for locked accounts

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I am encountering odd behaviour with `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure` `DatabaseFacade.CanConnect()` where this returns true even when a user account is locked, provided that the account has already logged in once during the applications lifetime.

Here are the steps I am following and what I encounter:

1. Start web application
2. User navigates to web page and enters their DB login
3. I check user details can connect to the DB using `canConnect()`, this returns true and page is displayed with some query results
4. I lock the user account in Oracle
5. The user logs out of the web application and refreshes the page
6. User refreshes web page and enters their DB login
7. I check user details can connect to the DB using `canConnect()`, this returns true and page is displayed with some query results - **Despite the user account being locked**
8. I restart web application (app pool reset/stop start)
9. User refreshes web page and enters their DB login
10. I check user details can connect to the DB using `canConnect()`, this throws an exception as the user account is locked

Why is it that if I lock the account the user can continue to connect to the database until the application stop/started/recycled? I am not using any caching in C#.

I am using `EFCore 2.2.6` with `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core 2.19.31`

The Db service is scoped per http request:

```
services.AddScoped<IOracleAuthenticationModule, OracleAuthenticationModule>();
```

OracleAuthenticationModule:

```
public struct UserConnection
{
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string DataSource { get; set; }
}

public OracleDbContext InitialiseUserDb(UserConnection connection)
{
    return InitialiseDb($"Data Source={connection.DataSource};User Id={connection.User};Password={connection.Password};Persist Security Info=True;");
}

private OracleDbContext InitialiseDb(string connectionString)
{
    DbContextOptionsBuilder<OracleDbContext> optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<OracleDbContext>();
    optionsBuilder.UseOracle(connectionString);

    OracleDbContext db = new OracleDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    if (db.Database.CanConnect())
    {
        return db;
    }
    throw new Exception("Unable to connect to Oracle database, please verify credentials");
}
```

Comment: the user who connects by the pool is the same that the one locking the account ? Are you locking the account by ALTER USER xxx ACCOUNT LOCK. ?

Comment: No, one user connects with account 'ABC' and then it is locked with another account 'ADMIN'

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that if the pool is executing an ALTER USER xxx ACCOUNT LOCK, to lock the db account used by the pool itself, **this command does not affect connections which are already opened within the pool**.

When you lock the user account in Oracle, if the user logs out, and log in again,  probably your pool is not opening a new connection, but reusing an existing one already available before the lock would have happened. Pools are normally configured to reuse existing connections, in order to avoid expensive operations as connect/disconnect.

That is what I believe that the lock does not affect until the pool try to open a new connection again, which it happens when you stop/start.

Try to have a look at

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/featConnecting.htm#ODPNT170

If you have an option to check v$session in your database, you would see how many connections are opened by the pool when you start your application and run your first request to the database.

Following Oracle doc

*When a new connection is opened, if the connection string is not an exact match to an existing pool, then a new pool is created. Prior to ODP.NET 12.1.0.2, only connection string attribute values had to match. Now, connection strings themselves must be an exact match. Keywords supplied in a different order for the same connection will be pooled separately. If a pool already exists with the requested signature, a connection is returned to the application from that pool.
When a connection pool is created, the connection pooling service initially creates the number of connections defined by the Min Pool Size attribute of the ConnectionString property. This number of connections is always maintained by the connection pooling service for the connection pool.
At any given time, these connections are in use by the application or are available in the pool.*

Comment: I am locking the account via a completely separate application to manage Oracle users. I assume this means that I should then terminate the user connection via C# programmatically then when the user logs out of the application?